# Flutter: Cant change sdk version

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

im trying to use:
firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
firebase_auth_oauth: ^1.0.1

when i do this i get this error:

```
because ui_learn depends on firebase_auth_oauth >=1.0.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because ui_learn depends on firebase_auth_oauth >=1.0.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

so i tried doing this: (pubspec.yaml)

```
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

then i got this error:

```
Because ui_learn requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because ui_learn requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

this is my flutter & dart version:

```
flutter version
Flutter 1.26.0-12.0.pre • channel dev • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
dart version
dart SDK version: 2.12.0-224.0.dev (dev) (Thu Jan 14 08:05:52 2021 -0800) on "windows_x64"
```

here is my pubspec file: https://pastebin.com/V5ks0Cb5

does someone know what is wrong?

Comment: have you tried a flutter clean and flutter pub get after changing the SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it running with these dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  android_intent: ^2.0.0
  archive: ^2.0.13
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  device_apps: ^1.3.0
  docx_template: ^0.2.7
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth_oauth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  flutter_form_builder: ^3.9.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.3.2
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  permission_handler: ^6.0.1
  signature: ^3.2.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  xml: ^4.4.0

dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
  crypto: ^3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your flutter version contains a prerelease version of the 2.12 Dart SDK.

Try running `flutter upgrade`.